# How to clean the deleted deployments history in Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I've been using Firebase Hosting for few months now.
The deployment history is quite handy with the possibility to rollback to a previous version.

The problem is, it is not always necessary to keep every previous versions. So I've deleted quite a lot of the previous deployments I made.

My problem is that all those deployments with the "deleted" status are still visible in my deployment list, making the list unnecessary long.

So, do you know a way to purge the list of all the "deleted" deployment ?

Answer (score 0):

No you need to delete them one by one. May be in future they add this feature.

Meanwhile you can track the issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/215)

Comment: Yes I know that you have to delete the previous deployments one by one.
My point is to remove all the "deleted" elements from the list.

Comment: This does not answer the question the OP stated